# Where can I ask about publishing an RSS feed app on Google Play?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm new here and I don't even know if this is the right place for my question, knowing that on Stack Overflow this type of question are not allowed.

I'd like to ask this:

> I finished my first app 3 months ago and since then I've been looking for an answer. My app is based on the news I take from *Corriere della Sera*'s RSSfeed page and other news sources, accessible from the World Wide Web but I'm not sure if I need a permission to do that and so I can't publish it on Google Play. I asked all, sent emails and calls for this problem but in the last 3 months nobody could help me because they didn't know.

Can you could suggest me where I can do this type of question?

Comment: Uh, you asked the creators of the News and RSS feeds for permission and they "didn't know"? They should be able to answer that... The question is AFAIK off-topic for all of SE as it is about legal/copyright issues (and possibly EULAs of Google Play), and if I'm not mistaken there will never be a legal.SE - both proposals were deleted, which is IMO the best thing to do because you should never take advice from random internet strangers regarding legal issues.

Comment: Sorry what means the acronym AFAIK? Anyway I tried many times to contact the creators by email and calls and they never answered

Comment: AFAIK means "as far as I know". And as long as the content creators don't give you permission, you don't have permission - it's their copyright after all. Depending on any "fair use" laws in your country you might get away with using small excerpts though, but this is still a topic you should discuss with a lawyer, not with random internet people.

Comment: And how can I do if I don't have a lawyer because I'm 16?

Comment: Being 16 doesn't stop you from contacting a lawyer, although it might be difficult to afford one. Still, the internet isn't the best place for legal issues because "some random person on SO said it's ok" isn't a good argument in court. Copyright can be frustrating but that's sadly just how it is... Anyways, I'd try to contact the creators again, maybe with a (paper) letter - these are probably answered more consistently than mail. You should also check if the sites have any licensing terms for their content and if they have a dedicated contact for licensing and third-party distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the situation and be one of the few who answered me. I've thought that Internet wasn't the best place to ask this too. I'll try to send paper letter and solve this. 
Thank you again :D

Comment: Not being able to contact a lawyer doesn't magically mean you do not have to. Perhaps wait until you are older, then.